# The question of receiver using struct in go

Tags: go, receiver

receiver's usage

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Person struct {
    name string
    age  int
}

func (p *Person) greeting1() {

    fmt.Println(p)  //&{0}
    fmt.Println(&p) //0xc000086018
    fmt.Println("Hello~")
}

func (p Person) greeting2() {
    fmt.Println(p)  //{0}
    fmt.Println(&p) //&{0}
    fmt.Println("Hello~")
}

type Student struct {
    //p Persion -> has a 
    Person // -> is a 
    school string
    grade  int
}

func test1(p Student) {
    fmt.Println(p)
}

func test2(p *Student){
    fmt.Println(p)
}

func main() {
    var s Student
    //s.p.greeting()
    s.greeting1()
    s.greeting2()

    test1(s)
    //test2(s) -> error 
}
```

When I use function in golang, If I declare value variable, when I use function I made, I had to put only value variable on paramter. like,

```
a int= 10;
func func1(param int){
 fmt.Println(fmt)
}
```

despite I declared Person as a value struct in Student struct,
as you see my code,
receiver functions(greeting1, greeting2) are getting two type parameters which are *Person, and Person.
I cannot understand that why greeting1 function is functioning without error, despite I put value variable as a parameter.
Thank you for you guys help.

Comment: "despite I put value variable as a parameter" but receiver is not your ordinary parameter. It gets special treatment. I wish I was able to give a more detailed answer. Gotta go re-read the spec.

Comment: From the [docs](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls): *"A method call x.m() is valid if the method set of (the type of) x contains m and the argument list can be assigned to the parameter list of m. **If x is addressable and &x's method set contains m, x.m() is shorthand for (&x).m()**"*

Comment: I'm very thankful for your  comment. it's helpful for me to understand this conception.

Answer (score 2):

Simplifying your example code to focus on the question / issue at hand:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Person struct {
    name string
    age  int
}

func (p *Person) greeting1() {
    fmt.Println(p)
    fmt.Println(&p)
}

func main() {
    var p Person
    p.name = "joe"
    p.age = 41
    p.greeting1()
}
```

Prints:

```
&{joe 41}
0xc00000c028
```

In short, the call `p.greeting1()` works because Go sees that `Person` (the type of `p`) has a `greeting1` method defined on a pointer receiver. So it treats the call `p.greeting1()` as equivalent to `(&p).greeting1()`. As mkopriva said in a comment, this is clearly laid out in the [Go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls):

> A method call x.m() is valid if the method set of (the type of) x
>   contains m and the argument list can be assigned to the parameter list
>   of m. If x is addressable and &x's method set contains m, x.m() is
>   shorthand for (&x).m()

This is done for convenience. Since pointer receivers are quite necessary and popular in Go - you need them whenever your method mutates the underlying object - it helps write cleaner code. You shouldn't be forced to write `(&p).greeting1()` where `p.greeting1()` would do - this substituion is unambiguous as the compiler knows what methods are defined on `Person`, and with which receivers.

Effective Go has a section on [pointer vs. value receivers](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#pointers_vs_values) that you should read. Here's one relevant quote:

> When the value is addressable, the language takes care of the common
>   case of invoking a pointer method on a value by inserting the address
>   operator automatically. In our example, the variable b is addressable,
>   so we can call its Write method with just b.Write. The compiler will
>   rewrite that to (&b).Write for us.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. It's helpful for me to understand the pointer in golang. I'll try to learn perfectly more. Thank you. Eli Bendersky.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Go is an object oriented language in its own way. It uses struct instead of classes. If you want to have a class, you must make a struct and relate some funcs to it by a pointer of that struct, So later you can create many independent object from your struct. You can use the function new which will return a pointer of your struct. Like:

```
p:=new(person)
p.name = "joe"
p.age = 41
p.greeting1()
```